# How to end a program when the line ends in a period character?

Tags: python

How do I end a program that reads an input line by line and it ends when there's a period (whitespace doesn't matter)?

For example:

```
input = "HI
         bye
              ."
```

the program should end after it reaches the period.

I tried doing two things:

```
if line == ".":
    break

if "." in line:
    break
```

but the first one doesn't consider whitespace, and the second one doesn't consider "." in numbers like *2.1*.

Comment: `if line[-1] == "."` will check if last character is a dot

Comment: Since whitespace doesn't matter, you should avoid it causing trouble by stripping the line of that whitespace (i.e. `line.strip()`). However, your string (as shared here) doesn't actually contain line endings - it's just invalid Python syntax. You'd want to use triple double quotes to do it like this. If you don't just want a period on a line by itself, but just want to check for a period at the end of the line, you should use `line[-1] == '.'`, as user @klutt suggests - or do both, to avoid problems with whitespace following the period, i.e. `if line.strip()[-1] == '.'`.

Comment: btw, don't use `input` as a variable name unless you intend to override that function

Answer (score 2):

You need `.strip()` to remove whitespaces and check the ending character with `.endswith()`:

```py
for line in f:
    if line.strip().endswith("."):
        terminate...
```

Comment: This assumes the period always comes by itself - which is likely not what OP actually wants.

Comment: @Grismar oh right. Fixed

Comment: DV removed  now :)

Answer (score 2):

```py
if line.replace(" ", "")[-1] == ".":
    break
```

.replace(" ", "") removes all white-spaces, and [-1] takes the last character of the string

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for strings called `endswith`, but honestly I would check if the string ends with a '.' through indexing.

```
if my_str[-1] == '.':
    do_something()
```

But this also depends on how your string is received. Is it literally from an `input`? Is it from a file? You may need to add something additional per the circumstance

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks:

- you should use triple double quotation marks if you want to literally include a multiline string
- I'm assuming you want to go over the input line by line, not just all at once
- don't use keywords and the names of builtin and standard (or other already defined) names as names, that's called shadowing

Here's what you might be after:

```
from io import StringIO

# you need triple double quotes to have a multiline string like this
# also, don't name it `input`, that shadows the `input()` function
text = """HI
       bye
            ."""

for line in StringIO(text):
    if line.strip()[-1] == ".":
        print('found the end')
        break
```

Note that the `StringIO` stuff is only there to go over `text` line by line. The important part, in answering your question, is `if line.strip()[-1] == ".":`

This solution also works when your text looks like this, for example:

```
text = """HI
   some words
            bye.   """  # note the space at the end, and the word in front of the period
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to end the string at the exact dot, you can try this:

```
input = '''HI
         bye
              .
        hello
          bye'''

index = input.find('.') # gets the index of the dot

print(input[:index+1])
```

Comment: The question wasn't to find the `.` or to split the string.